# How to add indented TOC entry using \addcontentsline?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, indentation

I am trying to manually add several subsections to my table of contents. How do I do this? When I use `\addcontentsline` the entries appear as sections (with no indent), not subsections. Specifically, how do I add a subsection so that it is indented? Also, how do I add roman numerals to all the manually added sections?

For example:

Input:

```
...

\tableofcontents

...

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Ch2}

...

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Ch2-1}

...

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Ch3}

...
```

Output:

CONTENTS

I. Automatically Added Section  ...  3

Ch2 ... 4

Ch2-1 ... 4    (I want to indent this)

Ch3 ... 5

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect{\numberline{\thesubsection} foo}` ;-) or `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{...}`.  But why are you adding it manually? If `\thesubsection` is defined to output Roman numbers the ToC will show them as well

Comment: They're added as `section`s because you use `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{..}`. If you want them to be formatted like `subsection`s, then use `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{..}`.